# Handling in retrofit two different types of objects on the same value in body

Tags: kotlin, retrofit

```kotlin
class Field: Serializable {
  
    @SerializedName("value")
    var value: Any? = null
}

class BodyClass: Serializable {

    @SerializedName("fields")
    var fields: List<Field>? = null

}
```

```kotlin
  val fieldsList: ArrayList<Field> = arrayListOf()
  val field = Field()
  field.value = 1
  fieldsList.add(field)

  val field_2 = Field()
  field_2.value = "Some string here..."
  fieldsList.add(field_2)

  val body = BodyClass().apply {
      this.fields = fieldsList
   }
```

API is here...

```
interface Api {
@POST("some/end/point_.php")
suspend fun addNewItem(
    @Header("token") token: String,
    @Body body: BodyClass
) 
}
```

Retrofit throws me "timeout" error message.

I tried to send some data with API call which have @POST method and JSON in body.  I need to add two different types of objects on the same `@SerializedName("value")` in body. See the code example and if can someone can help me it would be great.